# Unable to stub partial_search for chefspec

Tags: search, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I'm writing a cookbook that runs a partial search to find an attribute on other nodes. My chefspec test is failing with error `ERROR: Connection refused connecting to localhost:443`.  The search is instantiated as below:

```
describe 'my_recipe::default' do
  let(:test1_node) do
    stub_node('test1.com', platform: 'redhat', version: '6.3') do |node|
      node.set['my_recipe']['id'] = 101
      node.set['chef_environment'] = 'production'
    end
  end

  let(:test2_node) do
    stub_node('test2.com', platform: 'redhat', version: '6.3') do |node|
      node.set['my_recipe']['id'] = 102
      node.set['chef_environment'] = 'production'
    end
  end

  before do
    stub_search("node", "my_recipe:* AND chef_environment:production").and_return([])
  end
  let(:chef_run) do
    ChefSpec::Runner.new do |node|
      env = Chef::Environment.new
      env.name 'production'

      node.stub(:chef_environment).and_return(env.name)
      Chef::Environment.stub(:load).and_return(env)
    end.converge(described_recipe)
  end
  it 'updates the file' do
    stub_search("node", "my_recipe:* AND chef_environment:production").and_return([test1_node,test2_node])
    expect(chef_run).to create_template(/conf/my_recipe.cfg")
  end
end
```

Am I stubbing this incorrectly?

Comment: You have missed quote around `create_template(/conf/my_recipe.cfg")`

Comment: I removed the full path; the other quote is actually included in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stub_search` is for stubbing Chef Search. Partial search is supported by a cookbook and therefore not part of Chef core. Partial search uses a different API endpoint and uses POST instead of GET for the protocol.

You'll need to stub Chef's API calls to partial search. `stub_search` will not work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or provide a link?  I have searched extensively and have not found something that will work.

Comment: I've tried using           Chef::Recipe.any_instance.stub(:search).with(:node, "my_recipe:*").and_return([{"hostname" => "node1.example.com" }, {"hostname" => "node2.example.com"}])

Comment: Search != Partial Search!

Comment: I wasn't understanding what you meant.  Substituting the above 'search' with 'partial_search' was what I needed.